# Jenkins REST API to get job and job console log

Tags: c#, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

How to get the details of the job along with it console output using Jenkins REST API

example of builds

[image: Builds]

console output:

[image: console Output for the build]

I am using following commands to get the path of console log

echo $JENKINS_HOME/jobs/$JOB_NAME/builds/${BUILD_NUMBER}/log

echo $BUILD_URL/consoleText

It would provide the path to console log

http://localhost:8080/job/Echo/25//consoleText

but if i try to get the data from it using c#.net it would through me a exception

I am using following code to get the data

```
 public string Download_Contents(string URI)
    {
        string Data = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            using (var wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
                Data = wc.DownloadString(URI);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return Data;
    }
```

Exception:

[image: Exception]

Comment: What do you mean by console log?

Comment: @user7294900  I have updated the question

Comment: what's the exception?

Comment: Remote server  returned an error: 403 Forbidden

Comment: see https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Authenticating+scripted+clients

Comment: Thank you for the Help, I guess it would help me

Answer (score 20):

So for using the `consoleFull` i'm getting very **dirty** output using `curl`

example:

```
curl -s -S  -u "user":"password" "http://jenkins.domain.com/job/my_job_name/1077/consoleFull"
```

output:
many lines wrapped with html stuff:

```
 <span class="timestamp"><b>09:04:32</b> </span><span style="color: #00CD00;">ok:</span>
```

so my solution is to use:

```
curl -s -S  -u "user":"password" "http://jenkins.domain.com/job/my_job_name/1077/logText/progressiveText?start=0"
```

and you will get the same console log output without the html,span stuff

Comment: Dsaydon.. The solution worked for me. However i'm trying not to send the build number in the request, tried with lastbuild option with no success. Any suggestion here?

Comment: You probably will have to do it with several steps: 1) wait for the last build to finish 2) get the build number of the last build 3) get the console log.

Comment: I found getting the build number when you start the job then increment the build number by 1. That worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

we can get console log with Above URL mentioned
http://localhost:8080/job/Echo/25//consoleText

```
URL urls = new URL("http://localhost:8080/job/Echo/25//consoleText"); 
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urls.openConnection(); 
connection.setDoOutput(true); 
//connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.29 Safari/537.36");

System.setProperty("http.agent", "Chrome");
connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false); 
connection.setRequestMethod("GET"); 
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

// Convert to a JSON object to print data
/*HttpServletRequest request;*/
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        (connection.getInputStream())));
```

it worked for me if any queries please ping me

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use Jenkins API to obtain the crumbs based on the authentication (user/pass or user/token).

I'll paste below some code illustrating how to do that (it's powershell but the idea is the same and it's straight-forward to translate it to C#):

```
$user = 'user'
$pass = 'password'

# The header is the username and password concatenated together
$pair = "$($user):$($pass)"
# The combined credentials are converted to Base 64
$encodedCreds = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($pair))
# The base 64 credentials are then prefixed with "Basic"
$basicAuthValue = "Basic $encodedCreds"
# This is passed in the "Authorization" header
$Headers = @{
    Authorization = $basicAuthValue
}
# Make a request to get a crumb. This will be returned as JSON
$json = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://jenkinsserver/jenkins/crumbIssuer/api/json' -Headers $Headers
# Parse the JSON so we can get the value we need
$parsedJson = $json | ConvertFrom-Json
# See the value of the crumb
Write-Host "The Jenkins crumb is $($parsedJson.crumb)"
# Extract the crumb filed from the returned json, and assign it to the "Jenkins-Crumb" header
$BuildHeaders = @{
    "Jenkins-Crumb" = $parsedJson.crumb
    Authorization = $basicAuthValue
}
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://jenkinsserver/jenkins/job/Run%20a%20script/build" -Headers $BuildHeaders -Method Post
```

Source: https://octopus.com/blog/jenkins-rest-api

Answer (score 0):

> To make scripted clients (such as wget) invoke operations that require
>   authorization (such as scheduling a build), use HTTP BASIC
>   authentication to specify the user name and the API token.

See [Authentication](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Authenticating+scripted+clients) with samples

Answer (score 0):

Python example over here:

```
import requests

# create your own jenkins cred from jenkins setting page
USER = '***'
PASS = '***'
AUTH = (USER, PASS)

URL = "https://$JENKINS_URL/job/$JOB_NAME/$BUILD_ID/consoleText"

response = requests.get(URL, auth=AUTH)
open("my_log.txt", "wb").write(response.content)
```