# Is any any jenkins curl command which return the running logs of the build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

I am hitting the curl command which starts the jenkins job, but i also wanted to get the running logs of build is is possible with the help of curl command.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at

[Jenkins REST API to get job and job console log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45025231/jenkins-rest-api-to-get-job-and-job-console-log)
and
https://serverfault.com/questions/888176/how-to-trigger-jenkins-job-via-curl-command-remotely

Generally, you have to start job get handler and periodically call API

Comment: so you mean i have to hit the consoleText api until job does not pass or fail

Comment: In principle yes, but depends on what do you want to do if you want to trigger some action if build fails or success just add in your pipeline code Post-build task.

Answer (score 0):

The environment **BUILD_URL** represents the current build url, thus you can get the current build log as following in job post action

```
curl  -u 'jenkins_user:jenkins_pwd' -k "${BUILD_URL}consoleText"
```

Comment: i want some api which should wait until build is not completed